# Every principal ideal domain is a dedekind domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I thought about principal ideal domains (PID) and dedekind domains, and something confuses me a bit. I don't know if I have a thinking error.

I know that every principal ideal domain is a dedekind domain. Then I also know that if $R$ is a dedekind domain I have the following three statements which are equivalent

1. $R$ is a unique factorization domain (UFD)
2. $R$ is a principal ideal domain (PID)
3. $C(R)=0$ where $C$ denotes the classgroup of $R$

But I mean if I start assuming $R$ is a PID, then it follows that $R$ is a dedekind domain right? But then using the thoerem it tells me that it is equivalent to say that $R$ is a UFD. Would this mean that then every PID is equivalent to a UFD? I don't think so but I don't see where I missunderstood the theorem above.

Comment: It is only equivalent for a Dedekind ring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would this mean that then every PID is equivalent to a UFD?

No, this only means that every PID is UFD, which is true. You can't deduce "UFD $\Rightarrow$ PID" implication from that (which is false in general). For that to be true you would have to additionally assume "being Dedekind".

Comment: Ah so every UFD is a PID if we assume that it is dedekind?

Comment: @Wave yes, exactly.

Comment: Perfect thank you!